# Is the diameter of drain snake cable the bigger the better?

Tags: plumbing, sewer

Is the diameter of drain snake cable on the drain snake machine the bigger the better?

If it is for the same price, what is the advantage or disadvantage to have the bigger-diameter cable machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigger is better to a point. The problem comes when the size is two large to make a 90 or 2. If the cable is two large in lets say a 3" pipe the cable can chew through the side wall (I did this with a power snake) I find the smaller cable with a center core tends to hold up better and make it through more bends. You did mention "machine" On smaller hand snakes I have never found one to be two large If this is the type you are talking about. I use smaller hand style like a drill with snake drum for laterals and my big snake for main line work where I enter through a clean out or vent. A small snake can get twisted up in a large pipe when the clog is encountered.

Comment: Does it depend on the bends in the pipes?  I know when using stiff wire for pulling network cables I find that more than a total of 270 degrees is nearly impossible even with that thin stuff.